# How can I average ACROSS groups in python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
Participant   Type   Rating 
1              A       6
1              A       5
1              B       4
1              B       3
2              A       9
2              A       8
2              B       7
2              B       6
```

I want obtain this:

```
Type   MeanRating
A        mean(6,9)
A        mean(5,8)
B        mean(4,7)
B        mean(3,6)
```

So, for each type, I want the mean of the higher value in each group, then the mean of the second higher value in each group, etc.

I can't think up a proper way to do this with python pandas, since the means seem to apply always within groups, but not across them.

Answer (score 6):

First use [`groupby.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) to create a column that allows you to align the highest values, second highest values, etc.  Then perform another `groupby` using the newly created column to compute the means:

```
# Get the grouping column.
df['Grouper'] = df.groupby(['Type', 'Participant']).rank(method='first', ascending=False)

# Perform the groupby and format the result.
result = df.groupby(['Type', 'Grouper'])['Rating'].mean().rename('MeanRating')
result = result.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
  Type  MeanRating
0    A         7.5
1    A         6.5
2    B         5.5
3    B         4.5
```

I used the `method='first'` parameter of `groupby.rank` to handle the case of duplicate ratings within a `['Type', 'Participant']` group.  You can omit it if this is not a possibility within your dataset, but it won't change the output if you leave it and there are no duplicates.